# using elements in app.config file

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

Currently my app config settings are look like this

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="server=localhost;user=;port=;" />
    <add key="MS" value="MSr" />
    <add key="MassagesTable" value="Massages" />
  </appSettings>
```

I want to add an inner elements under `"MassagesTable"`  with names `columnOne` and `ColumnTwo`. How I can do it , and them to read it from the code .

Currently I do it like `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];`

Thanks for help.

Comment: Also note that connectionstrings have their own section in `web.config` since .Net 2.0. Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an example here: [Custom type application settings in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289388/custom-type-application-settings-in-asp-net/6289586#6289586)

Basically you can add any custom object as a setting, as long as you used 'typed settings' and the classes XML-serializable or have type converters. You should use `applicaitonSettings` section instead of `appSettings` for this.