# Using complex types in Visual Studio 2015 application settings file

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, propertygrid, application-settings

I see the great example of using application setting file with complex types: 
[Custom type application settings in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289388/custom-type-application-settings-in-asp-net/6289586#6289586) 
But I'm unable to get the shown editor:
[image]

I see only the simple one for XML editing:
[image]